# show that an expression $E(x,y)$ does not depend on x

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals, independence, square-numbers

**the question**

Let $a,b,d,e$ be real numbers with $a>d$ and $c=a^2+b^2, f=d^2+e^2, m=\frac{b-e}{a-d} , n=\frac{bd-ae}{a-d}$. Show that if $x\in [-a,-d] $ and $y=mx+n$, then

$$E(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+2ax+2by+c}+\sqrt{x^2+y^2+2dx+2ey+f}$$

does not depend on $x$.

**The idea**

We can write $E(x,y)= \sqrt{x^2+y^2+2ax+2by+a^2+b^2}+\sqrt{x^2+y^2+2dx+2ey+d^2+e^2}=\sqrt{(a+x)^2+(b+y)^2}+\sqrt{(d+x)^2+(e+y)^2}$

These got me thinking of the Minkowski inequality, I tried applying it, but I don't think it would help us show that the expression doesn't depend on x.(maybe the case of equality would...)

I also tried writing the variables in different forms using the given equalities, but honestly, I got to nothing useful and I got lost in all these variables.

Im pretty sure these are just put to distract us from the solution.

Hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide some context? Does this come from some geometric situation? Maybe there is some less algebraic-intensive reasoning and more elegant solution.

Comment: @b00nheT This is the original form of the problem i found in my book for algebra at school...

Comment: Okay… something’s off about this exercise… let me think of some solution.

Comment: @IONELABUCIU b00n heT is basically on the right track. All these expressions have very natural geometric interpretations. Once you figure those out the claim is virtually self-evident.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: Let us define the three points: $P(a,b)$, $Q(d,e)$ and $R(-x,-y)$. The expression is equal to the sum of 2 distances: $$\mathcal E = PR + QR$$

And it’s not difficult to prove that $P, Q,R$ lie on the same line by proving that this equation holds true (the LHS is the slope of $PR$, the RHS is the slope of $PQ$. [The 3 points are colinear if and only if the two slopes are equal](https://byjus.com/maths/collinearity-of-three-points/)):
$$\frac{b+y}{ a+x} = \frac{b-e}{a-d}$$
By consequence
$$\mathcal E = PQ = \text {const}$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your idea. May I ask you how can I show that those points are collinear (I never demonstrate it using coordinates)

Comment: @IONELABUCIU it suffices to prove the formula I wrote above holds true: this formula is equivalent to $y = p(a,b,c,d) \cdot x + q(a,b,c,d)$ (it’s not difficult to compute $p,q$). And then you will realize that $p = m$ and $q=n$ (which is the given condition)

Comment: But how to prove lines PR and PQ have same slope?

Comment: @Narasimham $(b+y)/(a+x)$ is the slope of $PR$ and $(b-e)/(a-d)$ is the slope of $PQ$. The 3 points lie on the same line if the two slopes are equal. And it is the equation that I wrote in the answer: $$\frac{b+y}{ a+x} = \frac{b-e}{a-d}$$

Comment: @Narasimham Exactly!

Comment: Clear. I understand that if $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+2ax+2by+a^2+b^2}+\sqrt{x^2+y^2+2dx+2ey+d^2+e^2}==\sqrt{(a-d)^2+(b-e)^2}, $ then E(x,y) does not depend on $x$ or $y$, right?